# AngularJS: Detect programmatically changed location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application I have saved state. Based on saved state I want to open a particular location. Also, the same location can be opened by clicking on an appropriate link from the UI.

The problem is that the logic is different based on how the location was changed, whether from the UI or from the controller by using `$location.path(...)`.

Is there a standard approach that would distinguish these cases?

Comment: Did you look at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options ?

Comment: Thanks, looking there